# Resize the image if it's too big, send it to the database and to the image folder

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, image-resizing

I have a problem with resizing my image and uploading it to the database and my image folder. I've tried a few things, but still can't figure it out.
Here is my code:

```
// AJAX in the <head> HTML tag
$(function(){
$('#add_recipes_form').on('click', '#add', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    let sendForm = true;

    let fileInput = document.querySelector('#upload_image');
    let image = new Image();
    image.src = URL.createObjectURL(fileInput.files[0]);
   
        // sendForm = form validation

    if (sendForm){
        image.onload = function() {
        let width = image.naturalWidth;
        let height = image.naturalHeight;
        if (width > 1920 || height > 1080) {
            let canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
            let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
            canvas.width = 1920;
            canvas.height = 1080;
            ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            canvas.toBlob(function(resizedImageBlob) {
                let form = document.querySelector('#add_recipes_form');
                let formData = new FormData(form);
                formData.set('image', resizedImageBlob, 'resized-image.jpg');
                $.ajax({
                    type: "post",
                    url: 'Php/add-recipes.php',
                    data: new FormData(form),
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    success: function(){
                        $("#add").addClass('sent');
                    },
                    error: function(){
                        $("#add").addClass('error');
                    }
                });
            }, 'image/jpeg');
        }
        }
    }
});
});
```

```
// shortened HTML form
<form method="POST" action="Php/add-recipes.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="add_recipes_form" class="add-form">
  <div class="input-div s1-image">
    <label for="image">Image (jpg, png)*</label>
    <label for="upload_image" id="file_style">Choose image</label>
    <input type="file" style="display:none;" id="upload_image" name="image" accept="image/*" onchange="loadFile(event)" class="required2">
  </div>

  <div class="form-s1-right">
    <img id="output" src="Images/placeholder-image.svg" alt="Uploaded Image">
    <script>
    var loadFile = function(event) {
        var output = document.getElementById('output');
        output.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
        output.onload = function() {
        URL.revokeObjectURL(output.src);
        }
    };
    </script>
  </div>
</form>
```

```
// shortened PHP script
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "cookbook");
                    
    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $image = $_FILES['image']['name'];

    $sql = "
      INSERT INTO
      recipes(`name`, `image`) 
      VALUES('$name', '$image');
    ";
                
    $target = "../Recipe_img/".basename($image);

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target)) {
    }

    $var = mysqli_multi_query($con,$sql);

mysqli_close($con);
```

Note: there is much more code, I wanted to show only the important part.
I can't figure out how to upload an image, resize it if necessary (if it's bigger than 1920 x 1080 px) and send it to the Recipe_img folder (../Recipe_img) and to the database, so I can get the image name to use it later.
I did a few things (a few failed attempts with JS canvas), but nothing resized the image uploaded to the folder.
Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I don't see anything here which would even attempt any resizing. Where exactly are you stuck with this? Your post is vague about where things are going wrong, or what else you might have tried. [PHP can resize images](https://www.google.com/search?q=php+resize+image), have you attempted to do anything with that?

Comment: @ADyson Sorry, I should've specified. This is the clean version of the code without any attempts at resizing the image. The most I could do is resize the image that is in the html preview (when I right-clicked and downloaded it is was resized correctly). I was trying to do something to send it to the folder, but nothing helped. Honestly, I don't really know what went wrong, as this is the first time I was trying to do something like this. I found a few articles and even used that new chatbot, but nothing worked.

Comment: OK. We can't fix working code though. Normally people post their broken code and ask for help fixing it. If they don't, answers tend to get generic or speculative, or miss the point and the context somewhat, which usually makes them less useful. And/or sometimes we can't answer at all without that context. See also [ask] and how to make a [mre] of your issue. Thanks.

Comment: @ADyson I updated the AJAX code with a failed attempt. Honestly, I'd love to explain where exactly I'm stuck and what's the problem, but I'm not really sure. This is the first time I'm doing something like this, so most of the code is just a changed version of what I found online. I know that the image from the input should be in canvas and somehow sent to the folder and the database, but I only know how to do the normal version without resizing.

Comment: Thanks. Well you seem to be adding `resizedImageBlob` to the Form Data. Does that make it into `$_FILES['image']` on the PHP side? Can you save it? And if so, has it been resized (presumably not)? Remember we can't run all your code, so you will need to narrow it down a bit by doing some simple debugging.

Comment: 1. ```$image = $_FILES['image']['name'];``` when using echo it gives me the normal name of the file if that's what you are asking. 2. When right-clicking and trying to save the preview image on the page this is the name of the image: "3979cfb9-8683-40ba-b11f-aa4a2770b2bc" and I have a network error. The image is uploaded to my folder (not resized) and the image name is in the database.

Comment: Hm. I think you would be better trying to do the resizing on the server-side using GD, similar to the example below.

Comment: I think I've managed to successfully implement that into my code with GD. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

I think you can resize the image in php using [GD](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php)

```
function resize_image($file, $w, $h, $crop=FALSE) {
    list($width, $height) = getimagesize($file);
    $r = $width / $height;
    if ($crop) {
        if ($width > $height) {
            $width = ceil($width-($width*abs($r-$w/$h)));
        } else {
            $height = ceil($height-($height*abs($r-$w/$h)));
        }
        $newwidth = $w;
        $newheight = $h;
    } else {
        if ($w/$h > $r) {
            $newwidth = $h*$r;
            $newheight = $h;
        } else {
            $newheight = $w/$r;
            $newwidth = $w;
        }
    }
    $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
    $dst = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);
    imagecopyresampled($dst, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);

    return $dst;
}

$target = "../Recipe_img/".basename($image);
$img = resize_image($target, 1920, 1080);
```